# Remove base domain cookies from a subdomain using Java filter

Tags: java, cookies, servlet-filters

I'm creating a Java filter hosted from domain **test.example.com** that will remove certain cookies based on their names (the list of banned cookie names are stored in the init configuration of the filter).

Now, I have cookies coming from another site which have domain attributes set to **.example.com**. Some of these cookies needs to be blocked/removed by the filter I'm developing.

I've read online articles including some stackoverflow posts related to cookie domain matching. I'm quite sure that these cookies having the domain attribute **.example.com** should be accessible from subdomain **test.example.com**. In fact, using debug I can verify that was able to access these cookies. However, I have problems removing them by invoking `setMaxAge(0)` and adding it back to the response via `addCookie`. It turns out that cookie is getting duplicated, instead of being deleted.

I wonder if it is ever possible to remove a cookie with a domain attribute **.example.com** (base domain) from **test.example.com** (subdomain). Or cookie deletion will only be possible if I'm executing my Java filter from the base domain only - which is **example.com**?

Here's a snippet of my code:

```
if (cookieBlockList != null) {
    Cookie[] cookies = httpRequest.getCookies();
    for (int i=0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
        String cookieName = cookies[i].getName();

        for(int j=0; j < cookieBlockList.length; j++) {
            if (cookieName.equalsIgnoreCase(cookieBlockList[j])) {
                Cookie cookie = new Cookie(cookieName, "");
                cookie.setMaxAge(0);
                httpResponse.addCookie(cookies[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}
filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A new cookie is created in your code, but it's unused. Add it to the response (instead of `cookies[i]`). Try setting a domain of the cookie to match the one from the request:

```
Cookie cookie = new Cookie(cookieName, "");
cookie.setDomain(cookies[i].getDomain());
cookie.setMaxAge(0);
httpResponse.addCookie(cookie);
```